Xarray return the dimensional information for minimum
When we handle the climate model output, we often get a NetCDF file with dimensions including member, lon, lat. Foe every member, how do we get the minimum of data, the lon and the lat of the data?
What We Have
Let's start with an Xarray DataArray, which has dimensions with member, lat, lon
member = range(30)
lat   = np.linspace(10,90,81)    # len(lat)=81
lon   = np.linspace(-50,50,101)  # len(lon)=101
da    = xr.DataArray(
    data = np.random.random([30, 81, 101]),
    dims = ['member','lat','lon'],
    coords=dict(
        member = member, 
        lat    = lat,
        lon    = lon,
    )
)
print(da)

    <xarray.DataArray (member: 30, lat: 81, lon: 101)>
    array([[[0.2891831 , 0.15339252, 0.11480441, ..., 0.52430944,
             0.1713771 , 0.67480492],
            [0.2033522 , 0.14739973, 0.28882198, ..., 0.37215926,
             0.36807609, 0.71486314],
            [0.31566454, 0.09916745, 0.01528857, ..., 0.08635732,
             0.14854258, 0.19532821],
            ...,
            [0.17011999, 0.35888976, 0.75866957, ..., 0.05882159,
             0.78562657, 0.2738246 ],
            [0.45221776, 0.51605168, 0.83711006, ..., 0.98703641,
             0.54330316, 0.27072401],
            [0.64459723, 0.31273233, 0.30999083, ..., 0.94173884,
             0.12521629, 0.21233589]]])
    Coordinates:
      * member   (member) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
      * lat      (lat) float64 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 ... 86.0 87.0 88.0 89.0 90.0
      * lon      (lon) float64 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 -47.0 -46.0 ... 47.0 48.0 49.0 50.0

What We Want
For every member, I want to get the minimum of the data, and its lon/lat information. So, the expected result could be an DataArray of Pandas Dataframe, like the following structure:
Output:
member : 0,    1,    2,...,     29
lon:     lon0, lon1, lon2, ..., lon29
lat:     lat0, lat1, lat2, ..., lat29

I have tried the da.min() or the da.argmin(), but it seems not work well.

Does this answer your question? How to get the coordinates of the maximum in xarray?

To get the minimum value of each member, use the dim argument to xr.DataArray.min to specify the dimensions to search over for the minimum:
In [11]: print(da.min(dim=("lat","lon")))
Out[11]:
<xarray.DataArray (member: 30)>
array([4.32884960e-04, 3.23263151e-05, 2.52212862e-04, 1.39290397e-04,
       1.03388171e-04, 3.42601737e-04, 1.25899786e-04, 3.50275712e-05,
       1.02502663e-04, 1.11044375e-05, 5.60118385e-05, 6.03876382e-05,
       3.23660119e-05, 7.99600712e-06, 2.35357346e-04, 1.12115490e-04,
       1.59178515e-05, 1.02704364e-04, 1.49878646e-04, 9.53773405e-05,
       4.52332895e-04, 7.84283815e-05, 1.31939758e-04, 5.38869542e-04,
       1.51267294e-04, 1.71203583e-05, 1.42057232e-05, 2.00753139e-05,
       3.89374167e-05, 6.93856653e-05])
Coordinates:
  * member   (member) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

To also get the lat/lon values of the minima, you can use the following expression to select the minimum values in the xr.DataArray:
In [12]: da.isel(**da.argmin(dim=("lat","lon")))
Out[12]:
<xarray.DataArray (member: 30)>
array([4.32884960e-04, 3.23263151e-05, 2.52212862e-04, 1.39290397e-04,
       1.03388171e-04, 3.42601737e-04, 1.25899786e-04, 3.50275712e-05,
       1.02502663e-04, 1.11044375e-05, 5.60118385e-05, 6.03876382e-05,
       3.23660119e-05, 7.99600712e-06, 2.35357346e-04, 1.12115490e-04,
       1.59178515e-05, 1.02704364e-04, 1.49878646e-04, 9.53773405e-05,
       4.52332895e-04, 7.84283815e-05, 1.31939758e-04, 5.38869542e-04,
       1.51267294e-04, 1.71203583e-05, 1.42057232e-05, 2.00753139e-05,
       3.89374167e-05, 6.93856653e-05])
Coordinates:
  * member   (member) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
    lat      (member) float64 44.0 34.0 73.0 38.0 34.0 ... 60.0 45.0 72.0 18.0
    lon      (member) float64 26.0 -44.0 -35.0 -10.0 ... 31.0 -3.0 39.0 4.0

To understand what happens in the latter code, note that xr.DataArray.argmin returns a dict, with dimension names as keys, and indices stored as xr.DataArray as values :
In [4]: da_argmin = da.argmin(dim=("lat","lon"))

In [5]: type(da_argmin), list(da_argmin.keys())
Out[5]: (dict, dict_keys(['lat', 'lon']))

In [9]: da_argmin.values()
Out[9]: 
dict_values([<xarray.DataArray (member: 30)>
array([39, 69, 68, 21, 70, 57, 29, 30, 15,  2, 70, 54, 78, 14, 29, 71, 61,
       16, 25, 76,  2, 20, 27,  6, 49, 60, 66, 52, 26, 51])
Coordinates:
  * member   (member) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29, <xarray.DataArray (member: 30)>
array([ 89,  54,  95,  86,  57,  53,  66,   4,  90,  89,  10,  52,  42,
        22,  45, 100,  56,  26,  10,  31,   8,  49,  67,  73,  88,   1,
        97,  77,  31,  88])
Coordinates:
  * member   (member) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29])

Thus, the ** applied to the dict result will pass the indices of the minima as keyword arguments, equivalent to the following, longer notation as explained also here:
In [11]: da.isel(lat=da_argmin['lat'], lon=da_argmin['lon'])
Out[11]: 
<xarray.DataArray (member: 30)>
array([2.20804323e-05, 1.29566925e-04, 8.94132619e-05, 6.22424066e-05,
       1.01704441e-04, 3.96837506e-04, 2.13540624e-05, 2.57184680e-05,
       2.13831774e-04, 5.97121613e-05, 3.18513272e-04, 6.09456759e-05,
       1.81003659e-04, 1.27158824e-04, 1.32417375e-04, 8.89046404e-05,
       3.08030058e-05, 3.90856272e-06, 1.50228907e-05, 4.21477714e-05,
       8.58276550e-05, 2.09444784e-06, 2.40065453e-05, 1.99078727e-04,
       1.01321626e-05, 1.74682352e-04, 4.33367635e-05, 1.04487623e-04,
       1.75087974e-05, 3.78620897e-05])
Coordinates:
  * member   (member) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
    lat      (member) float64 49.0 79.0 78.0 31.0 80.0 ... 76.0 62.0 36.0 61.0
    lon      (member) float64 39.0 4.0 45.0 36.0 7.0 ... 47.0 27.0 -19.0 38.0


Thanks, seems perfect. But could you explain a little bit about the double * means?
